# Security considerations for TCP client request / server response of non-sensitive information

Tags: c, security, sockets, tcp

I have read several similar topics on stackoverflow in which fellow programmers discourage the practice of using simple client/server applications and raw TCP sockets for communication.  I acknowledge that there are concerns but for what I'm trying to accomplish I don't see any other reasonable way.

Here is what I'm planning:

I have a simple working prototype client/server that I wrote in C.  The client application sends a request to my server to remotely execute code, generates a value and then relays this value to the client.  The transmitted data is not sensitive, will only be held in RAM and will be rejected if it exceeds a predefined length.  If I run a (hardened) dedicated server with the sole purpose of remote code execution to generate a response are there any security issues I'm overlooking?

I am less worried about my server being compromised and more worried about possible harm to client computers.  I'm not blind to the potential that my server gets hacked - I'm just trying to convey that their won't be any sensitive data on it even if it does get compromised.  I don't see how anything malicious could be injected (mitm) given the narrow scope of the data being transmitted but maybe I'm naive and overlooking something?  Please let me know.

I could accomplish this over HTTP with a re-write trick but that is convoluted, I'll incur more overhead than I want and I'm unsure it would be any safer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think about the possibilty of your server being damaged or wiped or even powered off by an intruder. Anything involving remote execution of code rings my alarms. You must at least use a secure client authentication scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  The remote code would execute on a server in my possession and clients won't be receiving any instruction from my server to do any remote execution - they will just receive a string.  I know what I'm proposing has several drawbacks like server overload or power outage as you propose.  For now I'm just concerned about not creating a security problem for any users.  If I used openssl or an some other client auth scheme would that be sufficient?

Comment: SSL with mutual authentication plus an authorization step at the server is sufficient. The server needs to check that the authenticated client identity is permitted to perform the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Confidentiality - not needed if you feel data is not sensitive

authentication - certificates can be used to make sure client talks to real server. Pls check openssl

Make sure the server is running with reduced privilege rather than root so that server can't be compromised completely in case of memory corruption attacks.

Using HTTP won't make any difference, HTTP uses TCP connections at transport layer.
HTTPS would be a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks, I did look into openssl a while back but wasn't sure if it would be necessary.  You confirmed my suspicions about HTTP since it is just a layer on top - I just thought I'd throw that suggestion out there since I wasn't completely sure.